# how to set the column value of one dataframe depending on whether the value in another column is included in the specific column of another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge, anaconda

How to set up the value of one column of a dataframe depending on whether the value in another column of the dataframe is included in a specific column of another dataframe. If it is included the number is 1, if not,0. For example: I have two dataframes:

```
a={'age':[22,38,26,62,198,27],'no':[1,2,3,4,5,6]} 


TableB= {'name': ['Braund', 'Cummings', 'Heikkinen', 'Allen','Mary','Celina','Roger'],
'age': [22,38,26,35,41,22,38],
'fare': [7.25, 71.83, 0 , 8.05,7,6.05,6], 
'survived?': [False, True, True, False, True, False, True]}
```

I would like to check if every number in the 'age' column of a is included in the 'age' column of TableB, if it is included, add a column 'Observer' in a and set the value to 1,if not,0.

```
I have tried this:

a['age'].isin(TableB['age'].set_value('Observer',1)
```

expected results are as follows, but my result is that all the values in the observer column of a is 1.

```
a={'age':[22,38,26,62,198,27],'no':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'observer':[1,1,1,0,0,0]}
```

Comment: `a={'age':[22,38,26,62,198,27],'no':[1,2,3]} ` how did you convert this to a dataframe?

Comment: Sorry  it was a mistake I have corrected it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a={'age':[22,38,26,62,198,27],'no':[1,2,3,4,5,6]} 
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
print (a)
   age  no
0   22   1
1   38   2
2   26   3
3   62   4
4  198   5
5   27   6

TableB= {'name': ['Braund', 'Cummings', 'Heikkinen', 'Allen','Mary','Celina','Roger'],
'age': [22,38,26,35,41,22,38],
'fare': [7.25, 71.83, 0 , 8.05,7,6.05,6], 
'survived?': [False, True, True, False, True, False, True]}

TableB = pd.DataFrame(TableB)
print (TableB)
        name  age   fare  survived?
0     Braund   22   7.25      False
1   Cummings   38  71.83       True
2  Heikkinen   26   0.00       True
3      Allen   35   8.05      False
4       Mary   41   7.00       True
5     Celina   22   6.05      False
6      Roger   38   6.00       True
```

You can cast boolean mask to integer for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
a['observer'] = a['age'].isin(TableB['age']).astype(int)
```

Alternative solution is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
a['observer'] = np.where(a['age'].isin(TableB['age']), 1, 0)
```

```
print (a)
   age  no  observer
0   22   1         1
1   38   2         1
2   26   3         1
3   62   4         0
4  198   5         0
5   27   6         0
```

If working with dictionaries then use list comprehension with `if-else` and test membership by `in`:

```
a={'age':[22,38,26,62,198,27],'no':[1,2,3,4,5,6]} 

TableB= {'name': ['Braund', 'Cummings', 'Heikkinen', 'Allen','Mary','Celina','Roger'],
'age': [22,38,26,35,41,22,38],
'fare': [7.25, 71.83, 0 , 8.05,7,6.05,6], 
'survived?': [False, True, True, False, True, False, True]}


a['observer'] = [1 if x in TableB['age'] else 0 for x in a['age']]
print (a)
{'age': [22, 38, 26, 62, 198, 27], 'no': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'observer': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a={'age':[22,38,26,62,198,27],'no':[1,2,3,4,5,6]} 
TableB= {'name': ['Braund', 'Cummings', 'Heikkinen', 'Allen'],
'age': [22,38,26,35,41,22,38],
'fare': [7.25, 71.83, 0 , 8.05,7,6.05,6], 
'survived?': [False, True, True, False, True, False, True]}
 a['observer']=[];

for i in a['age']:
  if i in  TableB['age'] :
     a['observer'].append(1)
  else :
      a['observer'].append(0)
```